# UniswapV2 addLiquidityETH() reverting when trying to deploy to ganache locally

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache, truffle-migration, uniswap

I'm trying to locally deploy a contract similar to sushiswap, but I keep getting a revert from `addLiquidityETH()`, no message other than `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

```js
//module.exports = function(deployer) {};
const SushiToken = artifacts.require("SushiToken");
const MasterChef = artifacts.require("MasterChef");
const SushiBar = artifacts.require("SushiBar");
const UniswapFactory = artifacts.require("UniSwapV2Factory");
const UniswapRouter = artifacts.require("UniswapV2Router02");
const MockERC20 = artifacts.require("MockERC20");
const SushiMaker = artifacts.require("SushiMaker");

const migration = async function(deployer,network,accounts) {
    await Promise.all([
        deployToken(deployer,network,accounts),
    ]);
};

module.exports = migration;

async function deployToken(deployer,network,accounts) {

    if( network === 'test' ) {
        
        dev_addr = accounts[9];
        account1 = accounts[8];

        await deployer.deploy(SushiToken);
        let sushiToken = await SushiToken.deployed();

        await deployer.deploy(MasterChef, SushiToken.address, dev_addr, 25, 0, 0);
        await deployer.deploy(SushiBar, SushiToken.address);

        let factory = await deployer.deploy(UniswapFactory, dev_addr);
        let wethToken = await deployer.deploy(MockERC20, "Wrapped Ether", "WETH", 1000);
        let anotherToken = await deployer.new(MockERC20, "Another Token", "AT", 1000000000000); 

        let poolToken = 0x0;
        if(( (await factory.getPair(wethToken.address, anotherToken.address)).toString()) === '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
            poolToken = await factory.createPair(wethToken.address, anotherToken.address);
        }
     
        let router = await deployer.deploy(UniswapRouter, UniswapFactory.address, dev_addr);

        await deployer.deploy(SushiMaker, UniswapFactory.address, SushiBar.address, SushiToken.address, wethToken.address);


        await sushiToken.approve( accounts[0], 10000000000);
        await sushiToken.mint(accounts[0], 10000000000);

        try { // the error is somewhere in here
            await router.addLiquidityETH( 
                sushiToken.address, 
                100, 
                50,
                9000,
                accounts[0], 
                ~~((Date.now() + 1000*24*60*60) / 1000), // unix date 24h into the future
                {from: accounts[0], value: 10000, gas: 6000000}
            );
            
        } catch(err){
            console.error(err)
        }
    } 

}
```

I have tried different addressess too, as well as different amounts, but so far it always reverts.

// Edit:
accounts[0] through accounts[9] have roughly 100 ETH per account.

Comment: What is `~~((Date.now() + 1000*24*60*60) / 1000)`?

Comment: that's a unix date, exactly 24 hours into the future.

Comment: What does `~~` does?

Comment: The same as Math.floor()

Comment: And do you have `10000` wei in `accounts[0]`?

Comment: You can get rid of `gas: 6000000` BTW. Truffle handles that for you.

Comment: accounts[0] through accounts[9] all have roughly 100 eth in them (ganache automatically puts 100 eth in the first 10 accounts).

Comment: I know, but your question doesn't share that information explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113871/discussion-between-zimri-leijen-and-goodvibration).

Comment: What is the usage of `poolToken` in your code?

Comment: the pooltoken should be a token pair, however I don't think I am actively using it in this code.

For example SUSHI-ETH UNI-V2 LP

Comment: what was the problem? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Comin I think it's the router that needs to be approved IIRC

Comment: I'm having the same problem, were you able to solve it?